# Combine search predicates in Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How can I implement the equivalent of `:name_eq_or_description_cont`, which combines `_eq` and `_cont` predicates into the same search key, so that I can create a search field in the form as:

```
<%= search_field_tag :item, :name_eq_or_description_cont %>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I came across something like this, but it seems to need to be pre-configured on the back end. Not sure how I would pass Ransack::Constants::OR from the front end:

```rb
.ransack({title_cont: params[:q], id_eq: params[:q]}, { grouping: Ransack::Constants::OR })
```

Actually, update, this works:

```
Departure.order(search_order).limit(search_limit).ransack({m: 'or', name_cont: "20967", id_eq: "20967"}).result
```

Not sure what "m" is, but it seems to work.